# jQuery ui-slider multiply current value to a fixed integer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to multiply the current value of the ui-slider, and outputs the values by using this script.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  function output() {
     var value1 = parseInt($('#slider').slider('value'));
     var value2 = parseInt(value1 * 2);
     $('#current').text(value1);
     $('#slider-value').text(value2);
  }

  $("#slider").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 3,
      min: 0,
      max: 11,
      //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        output();
      }
  });
});
```

It does multiply perfectly, however, when I move the slider from right to left, the value is not displaying properly.

Here's jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kristianladd/f2wbq5nm/1/

Comment: is there a reason youre not using the ui.value inside of the slide function?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f2wbq5nm/2/

Comment: I tried it with ui.value, still got the same problem.
@j08691, try holding the slider and move it repeatedly from right to left, you'll see wrong values

Comment: I'm not seeing the wrong values you mention. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get a console error when using your https link, but if you convert to http, it works.

it messes up going from right to left, because your current code displays the previous value. so going right to left, it looks like it ticks up on the first left-to-right swipe because it uses the values above the current slide.

changed the slide callback to this

```
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#current').text(ui.value);
    $('#slider-value').text(ui.value * 2);
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2wbq5nm/3/

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks also for explanation. Seems like it's better to use ui.value